# React query disable loading in certain ocasion?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a query like this:

```
const query = useMyCustomQuery({ ...someParams });
```

Which is called on component mount.

Then, in the return of the component I do something like:

```
{ query.isFetching && <LoadingOverlay /> }
```

which displays a loading component over it.

Now I need to add a `refetchInterval` to refetch every 30 seconds.
The problem is the loading will be shown while it's refetching and I need for that not to happen, because I want to user to be able to see the list of items even while is refetching.

I know I can change the `isFetching` to `isLoading` to show it only on the first load, but I have other user triggered actions that make a refetch and I want those to still have the loading indicator.

Is there any way to differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 0):

useQuery() has an option called **keepPreviousData**. what this option do is if you have data from the server it will show them until you get the newest data from the server. Reference to **https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery**

for exmaple:

```
useQuery({
    queryKey: ["test"],
    queryFn: your_fetch_request,
    keepPreviousData
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change to `isLoading` but in addition, on the user actions that you want to force the loading screen on, you could call `queryClient.resetQueries({ queryKey })` in order to set it back to its initial state, followed by a `refetch` -- in the event handler. Take care since `resetQueries` is async.

I believe this would also force the `isLoading` back to true.

By doing this you are basically removing the state that was previously fetched, but since you are showing a loading overlay, it sounds like you want to avoid showing anything stale when they force-refresh so that's probably fine.